# Emit a value only when certain conditions are met, else emit another vlaue

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel with the following:

`enum Detection {NotTriggered, Triggered};`

`public Detection AlertState => _alertState.Value;`

`public DateTimeOffset? LastAlertTime => _lastAlertTime.Value;`

What I would like to do is have another property: `int AcknowledgementPriority {get;}` that returns `0` by default.  However I would like a timer that kicks off if `AlertState` becomes `Triggered` and `LastAlertTime` has a valid time.  That timer would after 30 seconds set `AcknowledgementPriority` to `1`.  If `AlertState` becomes `NotTriggered` at any point in time then `AcknowledgementPriority` would become `0` again.

I'm pretty sure I can use something like `Observable.From(1).Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(30))` for the "timer" portion but I'm struggling with the Rx way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public class TestVm : ReactiveObject
{
    public enum Detection { NotTriggered, Triggered };

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<Detection> _alertState;
    public Detection AlertState => _alertState.Value;

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<DateTimeOffset> _lastAlertTime;
    public DateTimeOffset? LastAlertTime => _lastAlertTime.Value;

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> _acknowledgementPriority;
    public int AcknowledgementPriority => _acknowledgementPriority.Value;

    public TestVm()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AlertState, x => x.LastAlertTime)
            .Where(t => t.Item2.HasValue)                               //If LastAlertTime has a valid time
            .Select(t => t.Item1 == Detection.Triggered                 //a timer that kicks off if AlertState becomes Triggered
                ? Observable.Return(1).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))  //Timer would after 30 seconds set AcknowledgementPriority to 1
                : Observable.Return(0)                                  //If AlertState becomes NotTriggered at any point in time then AcknowledgementPriority would become 0 again
            )
            .Switch()
            .StartWith(0)                                               //that returns 0 by default
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.AcknowledgementPriority, out _acknowledgementPriority);
    }

}
```

`Switch` is the key: It takes in an Observable of Observables and 'switches' to the latest observable emitted.